# Vaadin Session Timeout configurable using preferences

Tags: java, vaadin, session-timeout, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 and add-on plugin to implement Session time out when UI is idle for more than 3 mins. Here is the add-on plugin

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.anna</groupId>
   <artifactId>cleanupservlet</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

VaadinUI.java

```
@Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        // timeout for 3 mins
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(180);

        Responsive.makeResponsive(this);
        setLocale(vaadinRequest.getLocale());

        showMainView();
    }
```

VaadinServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "VaadinServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = VaadinServlet.class, productionMode = false, heartbeatInterval = 180, closeIdleSessions = true)
        public static class VaadinServlet extends CleanupServlet {

            @Override
            protected int getCleanupPollingInterval() {
                // how long to wait between session timeout checks
                return 2000;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean alwaysCheckUITimeOuts() {
                // if you want to ensure UI cleanup on every check
                // regardless of session timeout, default false
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I dont have web.xml to configure the inactiveInterval. Is there a way to configure the inactiveInterval and heartbeatInterval as given by the user in the Preference Dialog??

Or is there any way to implement Session Timeout which is configurable by the user??

Any help is appreciated.

TIA